# PostgreSQL: Return all rows from one table, joined with rows from another table

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.1

For each row in table foo I want to join it with a row from table bar.
The row from bar is that one with the same name as in foo and has the newest date that is older than the date in foo.

Example:

Table Fish:
A fisher is related to a fishdate, (e.g. when the fisher got a fish)

Table baits:
A fisher is related to baits, (e.g. what the fisher tries to fish with)

They could look like this:

Fishes:

```
 name   |      fishdate
-----------------------------
bob     | 2014-02-22 11:45:01
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:45:02
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:50:04
bob     | 2014-02-22 15:45:05
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:42:50
```

Baits:

```
 name   |        date         | bait
------------------------------------
bob     | 2014-02-22 11:41:01 | worm
bob     | 2014-02-22 11:42:01 | salomon
bob     | 2014-02-22 11:47:01 | fakefish
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:40:02 | salomon
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:41:02 | worm
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:49:04 | fakefish
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:36:04 | salomon
bob     | 2014-02-22 14:40:05 | worm
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:41:04 | worm
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:42:04 | salomon
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:49:04 | fakefish
```

What I want is the fishdates with the bait that was currently used by that fisher:

```
 name   |      fishdate       | bait
-------------------------------------
bob     | 2014-02-22 11:45:01 | salomon
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:45:02 | worm
alice   | 2014-02-22 12:50:04 | fakefish
bob     | 2014-02-22 15:45:05 | worm
alice   | 2014-02-22 14:42:50 | salomon
```

How do I do this in PostgreSQL 9.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a correlated sub-query.

Effectively it runs an SQL statement for each row in your data.  In this case it takes each date from `fishes` and finds the date from `baits` that comes immediately before it.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  fishes
LEFT JOIN
  baits
    ON  baits.name = fishes.name
    AND baits.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                        FROM baits   AS lookup
                       WHERE lookup.date <= fishes.date
                         AND lookup.name  = fishes.name
                     )
```

Comment: Does that return only columns name, fishdate and bait?

Comment: @SimonBosley - No, it returns all columns from both tables, but that's a task that I'm very happy to leave to the OP, it's not exactly difficult to select 3 columns from a list of 5.

Comment: Yes he's got this far, you would assume he can do it!

Comment: This query seems to work but it takes extremely long time to run. Even with only 30 records it takes seconds. Essentially fishes contain 300 000 entries and baits contain 750 000 entries. For optimization, it is safe to say the day in both dates are equal.

Comment: @ManneTallmarken - Provided that the `baits` table has an index on `(name, date)` knowing that the date-part will be the same isn't going to make a difference.  What indexes *do* you have?

Comment: Aaah, I didn't have that index, only name and date separately. Now it works extremely good! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select name,fishdate,bait from 
(
SELECT *, rank() over (partition by fishes.name,fishes.fishdate order by baits.date desc) ranked 
from fishes inner join baits using (name) 
where fishes.fishdate>=baits.date
) A 
where ranked = 1
order by fishdate
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1f64e).

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select distinct
  f.name,
  fishdate,
  last_value(bait) over (partition by f.name, fishdate order by date 
    rows between current row and unbounded following) bait
from fishers f
join baits b on b.name = f.name and date <= fishdate
```

See this working on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ac31/33) with your data.

It's rather elegant, even if I do say so myself.